# How to linking a users data to his future account at the time of signup in Stitch

Tags: mongodb, stitch

I would like to use Stitch to sign up users. Each user must have a unqiue **email** and a unique **user-name**.

This is important for applications like chats or forums, where users should not be forced to reveal their email when communicating.

I already implemented login with email and password as described here: https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/authentication/userpass/#authenticate-a-user

The problem is: 
How to securely save a user-name on signup? I could store a users desired name in a collection and merge it into his custom user data after initial login. In order to do that, I would need to grant the user write privileges to whichever collection holds pending names. This is unsafe, since he could now change the name after the fact or even change other peoples names while they are pending.

The user needs to choose his name at the time of signup. At this time the user is still logged in via anonymous credentials. Hence, I can not restrict users to changing only their own data since they are at this point sill anonymous. I see no way of linking a users data to his future account at the time of signup. Any idea to change that?

It would seem strange, if stitch lacked the functionalities to easily sign up users with a unique name/handle in addition to email address.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used  your exact software but in general  I  would approach the problem as follows:

1. When someone starts using the application anonymously, create a user object. The user at this point does not have  a reserved (i.e. globally unique) user name, or email address, etc. But the user still has an internal identifier.
2. Associate user-visible state with the user object. This could be done through server-side sessions or signed cookies. (Unlike unsigned cookies, cryptographically signed cookies permit server to store what would otherwise have to be stored in the server-side session in a cookie, and trust that the client hasn't tampered with the information by e.g. changing the user id).
3. When user registers, set the user name, email address, etc. on the existing user object. User id remains the same and allows the user to continue to have access to their anonymously-generated data.
4. Have a process for deleting anonymous users that don't register after some time.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your input. I am using Stitch since it encapsulates the process you of signing up users. So I really need Stitch specific advice.